# Stepping through Cucumber Tests

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, cucumber, gherkin

After some help as I've just moved over to Cucumber/Ruby in a new role, and I'm looking for a way to step through the code as I could when writing tests in C# (in VS).

This was so simple in VS and C#, just spin the test up and step through, line passes, goes green onto next line. Very quick way of stepping through and resolving multiple issues in one pass.

We're using VS to write the test, however it does not seen possible to step through when using Feature Files in cucumber?

Comment: did you google it? https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/06/29/debugging-cucumber-tests-with-ruby-debug/

Comment: Have you looked at [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug)?